# Vectorization of 1 bit Raster Images

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, raster, vector-graphics

I want to convert low-res, raster images that are composed of only two colors into a vector image.

My current approach is simple. I use the [Moore Contour](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/moore.html) tracing algorithm to "walk" around the edges of the shape. As I'm walking around the shape, I create simple lines that have the same slope as the pixels that are being traced. Once the slope changes, I close off that line, and start a new line. This leads to a list of lines that resemble a polygon created from each contour.

This approach has some obvious problems:

1. The lines are only closed into a polygon along each contour trace. This is because each contour converts into exactly one closed polygon, and currently I have no way of connecting the lines from one contour to another.
2. This algorithm can only model an image with lines. I would really like to be able to create vector images that have both lines and curves so that I have a more accurate representation of the bitmap image.

Before tracing:

[image]

After tracing (each color represents a different contour found).

[image]

Here are some examples of other types of images I'd like to be able to convert:

[image]

[image]

So my question is, what's a good algorithm that can take one of these images as input, and outputs a vector image that consists of curves and lines that model the original bitmap?

Comment: So this is an interesting problem and I'm kind-a surprised that no one has commented yet. On your example, do where would you place the nodes for say, the melty airplane looking one? My thought is that most algorithms are going to have trouble making a call when certain conditions are met, for example, all the pixels surrounding a cell being 1 value, for example, where the tail of the aircraft meets the noodle body; could you put up an example of what you would like to see for vectorization?

Comment: Haha, the "melty" airplane one you're referring to supposed to be a gun (but I see why you thought you it was an airplane). I now have a working solution for the vectorization. Once I have refined the algorithm and have it fully implemented in what I'm actually trying to do (rotation), I will post an answer describing what steps I took.

Comment: Hmm. So in a sense you want to do loss-less rotation. You know you *could* rotate them as pixels right? As an aside, I'm highly interested vectorization functions for a totally unrelated purpose. For me I'm interested in defining 'object's in raster. But I'm having difficulty with edges, or, how some rules work at edges where you have 7/9 pixels.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get loss-less rotation. The original post is [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/154413/unity-pixel-perfect-rotation). The solution wasn't good enough for me, so my new approach is to vectorize the outline and then color in the rest of the sprite afterward. As for cases like 7/9 pixels, I'm not sure. These cases really don't come up in the sprites I'm working with, but if you send some examples I could take a look.

Comment: So an example of the 7/9 issue would be near the tail of the melty airplane (or barrel of the gun). If one were going to use a focal function to determine the nodes for a vector transformation, these areas can be a problem. One algorithm i've used first goes through and tries to figure out the node locations for a raster, then tries to figure out how to connect them. I'll put some time into this this weekend and post some options I've tried previously, and hopefully work up a solution.

Comment: Did you get this to work? Thanks for sharing.